# Azure - App Service | App Service Plan | App Service (Slot)

Tags: azure

This is the first time I have used Azure, always published to our own servers so it was a learning curve - and MS are about as much use as the proverbial chocolate fireguard and any documentation doesn't really explain this.

Selected the S1 tier and, from VS, used the default settings to publish. For some reason it created two app services and I have been charged double the amount I was expecting. It's a very small MVC app with <$0.01 bandwidth so far.

I have just deleted the spurious one.

Now I am left with three items - App Service, App Service Plan and App Service (Slot). It was my understanding that I could publish up to 10 domains using the same service plan, and it would distribute the available resources, but the cost would remain the same (assuming low bandwidth).

That leaves me with a couple of questions. If I publish another site, I assume that this then becomes a second app service and charged at the same rate (so adding 10 domains would push it up from $2.40 a day to $24.00 a day). Is that correct? Or was my initial take correct and it was misconfigured? $750 a month for ten domains seems like a lot.

From VS I have this when I publish

```
Site URL -      ProjectName123456789.azurewebsites.net

Subscription -  MySubscriptionCode

ResourceGroup - ProjectName123456789ResourceGroup

ResourceName -  ProjectName123456789
```

I'm assuming that to publish another site I use the same Resource Group but a different resource name (and therefore a different site URL)?

=========================== UPDATE ==============================

If I create a new project (say MVC) then click publish and select Azure it will select the existing settings. Where is says 'App Services Setting' if I click the +

```
App Service (Windows)

Name - ProjectName987654321

Subscription Name - Same as before

Resource Group - LastProjectName123456789ResourceGroup

Hosting Plan - LastProjectName123456789Plan
```

It should create the new MVC site, but run under the existing charge rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when you create an "app service", it will automatically create an "app service plan" for it.
In this context:

- app service = application, website etc.
- app service plan = the computer that runs, that hosts the app service

When you have created your second or many "app service", you can decide whether you want it to be in a new plan (and it will create a new "app service plan") or use the existing one.

Note: one "app service plan" can host multiple "app services".

To find out the costs, I recommend the following website: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator

It is very important to note that regardless of whether you can enter the running hours in the calculator (default 730 hours), it will not be cheaper to stop the "app service plan" if you stop the "app service" it is hosting.
You will have to either delete the "plan" or scale it back to "free".

You can do this with runbook (Automation Account):

- Automation account: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/learn/automation-tutorial-runbook-textual
- Powershell module + example script: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/set-azappserviceplan?view=azps-11.0.0
  Example: `Set-AzAppServicePlan -Name 'ContosoASP' -ResourceGroupName 'Default-Web-WestUS' -Tier Free -WorkerSize Small`

Side note: if you scale it back to free, the custom domains will be deleted immediately.

Domain:
If you have your own domain, you have 2 options:

- Add "A" record + add TXT record for authentication
- Add "CNAME" record + add TXT record for authentication

These are free options (meaning azure doesn't charge you) if you don't buy the cert from them.

If you don't have your own domain, you can buy from azure. In this case the main domain will always cost money, the subdomain will not.
Basic custom domain without cert will be 11.99$/YEAR not monthly or daily.

Your assumption may be true.
If you make a new site (app service), it will get a `<resourcename>.azurewebsites.net` URL.
It's up to you whether it will be hosted by your existing plan or a new one, as I wrote above.

If I have answered your question please mark it.
For any other questions, please feel free to ask.

Comment: Hi KKI - there was no problem adding an SSL cert for an existing domain and a lot faster than the messing it takes with our own boxes. I had used the pricing calculator (so came out with $2.40 a day). Oddly wasn't charged for the cert, it came in as included. The main question being if an app service plan can host multiple app services, why did the price double when the default VS settings create an extra app service? What you are confirming is that I CAN create more apps in that plan and not be charges extra (except for SSL certs)?

Comment: Please see the table below. 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/
The first row "Web, mobile, or API apps" shows how many "app services" you can host with a single "app service plan".
The question is, of course, how much your app is using the vcpu and ram you have. Essentially, you can host an infinite number of "app services" with a single Basic or more expensive "plan".

"If multiple apps are in the same App Service plan, they all share the same VM instances"
REF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans

Comment: Also, the cert associated with the basic domain (<resourcename>.azurewebsites.net) is always free.

Comment: The SSL cert they provided was for MyOwnDomain.com not subdomain.azurewebsites.net

Comment: Ah - 'Standard Run production workloads' shows as unlimited. Thanks, it's slowly sinking in, but then it is Friday :-) Thank you. I did update the original post for clarification (belt and braces) before I upload another and make a mess of it.

Comment: Updated: Ahh okay, no problem ;)
-------------------------


The first ip ssl cert is always free. The second or more cost money.
[link](https://ibb.co/LSk7z0y)
You can see the pricing of the other cert here.

Maybe I don't understand, but what type of cert costs 2.4$?
What does the "Binding type" column in app service > settings > custom domain say?

To your main question, please add: what resource types exactly does Azure create?